# CUPS print job taking 5 minutes before releasing job

Tags: printing

I am working on Linux mint 19 with a Zebra GTK420D printer and using CUPS on a Linux OS as my print server to handle all requests from a python application that sends raw data to the printer. It always takes 5 minutes to hold the job and then it prints without issue after the 5 minutes is up. How do I get the job to print instantly instead of having to wait 5 minutes for each print job?

Comment: https://www.cups.org/doc/network.html Sounds like the lpr/LPD service timeout.

Comment: i agree, but I am connecting with the DNSSD instead of IPP/LPD/socket. how would I use the timeout option if I am connecting via USB to my print server?

Comment: I wasn't sure if LPD was involved. So: dunno. You can query the print server, of course, so it might make sense to start there. Later: even if DNSSD/Bonjour is being used, there is some sort of LPR type queue being called. lpstat, etc. might be a start.

Comment: i am reasonably sure the application is using lp to send to the print queue. the raw printer being used is setup to accept lpd over port 515. i can release the job manually through 'lp -i (job#) -H resume' with no problem and through the CUPS GUI and can cancel through the 'cancel -a' command in terminal. ive looked everywhere and I can't find a solid way to automatically release all new jobs unfortunately